# Mismatched argument count to recur in syntax quoted macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm creating a macro that will accept a sum in infix notation and return an equivalent list in prefix notation. Whilst the code probably isn't logically correct yet, I've run into the following error when calling the macro:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 0 args, got: 5, compiling:(/tmp/form-init1201331851685991945.clj:1:1)
```

Here's the macro's code:

```
(defmacro infixer [o1 outlist i1 i2 i3]
  `(if (empty? ~i3)
    (concat ~i1 ~i2)
    (if (= ~i2 ~o1) 
      ;then recur list of i2 i1 i3 at outlist tail
      (recur ~o1 
             (concat ~outlist (~i2 ~i1 ~(first i3)))
             ()
             ~(second i3) 
             ~(rest (rest i3)))
      ;else recur i1 at outlist tail
      (recur ~o1 
             (concat ~outlist ~i1) 
             ~i2 
             ~i3
             ~(rest i3)
      ))))
```

I'm using the following to test it, after which the above error is thrown:

```
(def s1 '(1 + 3 * 2 / 2 * 5 - 3))
(infixer * () (first s1)(second s1)(rest (rest s1)))
```

I can't see any `recur` targets, so shouldn't `recur` be seeing the five arguments after the macro name? I haven't used syntax quoting before, so my suspicions are that I've misunderstood how to use it. Please can someone explain why the error is being thrown?

Also, if I'm way off on the logic of trying to convert infix to prefix, feel free to point me in the right direction! I'm new to Clojure and FP so any guidance is extremely appreciated - thanks in advance.

Comment: if you call this macro from another function, then `recur` would be the recursion point for that function, since you can't use `recur` in a macro (as far as i know). Just replacing `recur` with `infixer` (generating macro recursively) should do the trick

Comment: Trying to write a macro tail-recursively is *possible*, but generally not the right approach (and just replacing the `recur` will not fix the issues). Instead, see something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/8622652/625403 for the proper way to write a recursive infix macro.